# Do for loop to read 'item' element in XML by google app script

Tags: javascript

I am developing the google app script to read news from xml source [here](http://www.bangkokbiznews.com/rss/feed/business.xm). But I have no idea how to read item element from xml to extract news titles and links. I also have some sample codes below. So could you please help me to guild how to code this issue?

```
function myFunction() {
  parseXml();
}
function parseXml() {
  //get the data from boardgamegeek
  var url = 'http://www.bangkokbiznews.com/rss/feed/business.xml';
  var news = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var document = XmlService.parse(news);
  var root = document.getRootElement();

  //set variables to data from bgg
  var newsTopic = root.getChild('channel').getChild('title').getText();
  var newsDate = root.getChild('channel').getChild('lastBuildDate').getText();
  var item = root.getChild('channel').getChild('item').getChild('title').getText();
   var link = root.getChild('channel').getChild('item').getChild('link').getText();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close to a solution. Try:

```
function parseXml() {
  var url = 'http://www.bangkokbiznews.com/rss/feed/business.xml';
  var news = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var document = XmlService.parse(news);
  var root = document.getRootElement();
  var channel = root.getChild('channel');

  var items = channel.getChildren('item');
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
    var title = items[i].getChild('title').getText();
    var link = items[i].getChild('link').getText();
    // Do something with item data (title, link)
    console.log(title + " " + link);
  }
}

parseXml();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try